# Django - filtering prefetch_related to today's date

Tags: python, django

Filtering prefetch_related.

I have two tables:

1. Student attendance data

```
class studentAttendance(models.model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  date = models.DateField()
  status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  objects = models.Manager()
```

2. Student personnel record

```
class Student(models.model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  objects = models.Manager()
```

Objective:

I want to have a "daily register" html form. When loading the daily register I want it to show the following columns:

First Name |
Last Name |
Status |

Next to it I will have checkboxes for the teacher to select "Present" or "Absent".

My issue:

I need to show a list of all "active" students and then also either display empty statuses for those that haven't signed in yet, or show the value that already exists for those students that have signed in.

I figure since one student can have many "days" in the attendance table, this counts as a 'prefetch_related' scenario, not 'select_related'. If I were going the other way, from the attendance table to the Student, then that would be a 'select_related', since only one row in the Student table would match. That was the way I was initially doing it, but then I quickly realised that for those students that hadn't signed in yet...their record wouldn't be pulled through.

So my first attempt to grab the prefetch is:

```
from students.models import Student
from datetime import date

student_data = Student.objects.filter(active=True).prefetch_related('student')
```

However, I need to filter the prefetch_related to be filtered against today's date. I am trying:

```
student_data = ...filter(date=date.today())
```

But I get an error:

"SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?"

I've seen plenty things on google around "prefetch_related(prefetech('student', queryset='')) but that doesn't seem to work and I get errors along the lines of "unexpected keyword "prefetch" etc.

Please help or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a little tip on Django models, you don't need to specify the id column, Django will do that for you automatically :).

Answer (score 1):

Your filter needs to be:

```
student_data = Student.objects.filter(
    active=True,
    student__date=date.today()
).prefetch_related('student')
```

To filter related fields with or without `select_related` and `prefetch_related` you need a double underscore.

See the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) for filtering.

Comment: That helped I think Dean, at least I am no longer getting the Syntax Error.  

I am slightly confused on two things:  

1) Why do I do a `__date=` but don't need to do that for `active=True`  

2) If I do: `for i in student_data: print(i)` That returns some objects however, if i do: `for i in student_data: print(i.student.status) # or print(i.student_status)` nothing seems to work...

Comment: Have a look at the docs I linked. For any related fields, so fields which are from another table, you must use `__` in Django only to filter them. So in your example you need to use `__` to filter any fields on the `studentAttendance` model from the `Student` model. So to filter `status` you would also need to: `Student.objects.filter(student__status)`. The `student` part of `student__status` is from the `related_name` you set.

Comment: You need use `__` only when using `.filter()`. For your second question the for loop will work with `i.student.status` however the relationship is not OneToOne. So `i.student` can technically return more than `studentAttendance` for a single `student`. Therefore, you need to use `i.student.all()` or `i.student.all()[0]` to get the first one. Have a look at these docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: ... more than one `studentAttendance`*** for a single...

Comment: It should return one-to-one. Appreciate that it is a many-to-one relationship but we have initially filtered it by using `date=date.today()` so either it'll be an empty set on return one row (going to look into how to make the fields date and student_id unique constraint...i.e. update or create).

Comment: Reading docs now. Starting to think my understanding is fundamentally flawed !